# Wrong field specified by update paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express

When I want to update/save the paypal express configuration in the magento 1.9.3.4 admin, it gives this message "Wrong field specified". ???
Regards,
gp

Answer (score 0):

You have one of your payments method that need `<dynamic_group>1</dynamic_group>`.

For example:

```xml
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <payment_method_code>
                    <dynamic_group>1</dynamic_group>
                </payment_method_code>
            <groups>
        <payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```